# Update one column does not works

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to update one column of my database. The column name is status and the type is Enum('waiting' , 'accepted' , 'rejected')
I want to update this column when I click on link:

```
<a href="requests/action?id=${vac.id}&a=accepted">Accept</a>
<a href="requests/action?id=${vac.id}&a=rejected">Reject</a>
```

Vacation.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.terafast.tem.model">
    <class name="Vacation" table="vacations" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="id" column="REQUEST_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="user" column="USER_ID" />
        <property name="reason" column="REASON" />
        <property name="duration" column="HOW_LONG" />
        <property name="status" column="STATUS" />
        <property name="start" type="date" column="START_DATE" />
        <property name="created" type="date" column="CREATED_AT" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requests/action")
public String statuHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    String status = request.getParameter("a");
    vacationDao.actionStatus(id, status);

    return "redirect:/admin/requests";
```

I can successfully get these two GET values. (id , a). My VacationDAOImpl:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void actionStatus(int id, String action) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Vacation where id = :reqid ");
    q.setParameter("reqid", id);
    Vacation vacation = (Vacation) q.list().get(0);

    vacation.setStatus(action);
    session.update(vacation);
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.terafast.tem" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.terafast.tem.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="vacationDoa" class="com.terafast.tem.dao.VacationDAOImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have seen this approach in [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/).
When I click on links, everything looks good. But the column value does not change. Could someone explain this problem?

Comment: can you show your spring context file.

Comment: root-context or servlet-context?

Comment: file where you have defined `transactionManager`

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Why you are useing `sessionFactory.openSession()` instead of `getCurrentSession`? Also you are not closing it - which is required if you manage sessions you open yourself.

Comment: @PKa do you find any exception on console?

Comment: @PKa try after moving `<context:component-scan base-package="com.terafast.tem" />` to application context xml (root-contex) and even `transactionmanager` and dao beans supposed to define in application context file